# Need help - Java if/else statement with an int and String

Tags: java

Here's my code in full. I realise it is not finished, but I am having problems with the ISBN parameters part. When I compile, it says "incompatible types" highlighting 'return "Incorrect ISBN";'

```
class Book{
    private String title;
    private int ISBN;
    private String authorLastName;
    private String authorFirstName;
    private int yearPublished;

   public Book(){
   }

   public Book(String newTitle, int newISBN, String newAuthorLastName, 
   String newAuthorFirstName, int newYearPublished){
       title               = newTitle;
       ISBN                = newISBN;
       authorLastName      = newAuthorLastName;
       authorFirstName     = newAuthorFirstName;
       yearPublished       = newYearPublished;       
   }

   public String setTitle(String newTitle){       
       if(title.length()> 3){
        return title;
       }else{
           return "Title too short.";
       }
   }

   public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
       if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
           return ISBN;
       }else{
           return "Incorrect ISBN";
       }
   }    
}
```

If you guys could I would be very grateful!

Comment: Do you know what a return type and a return statement are?

Comment: Why do your `set` methods not set anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){
```

means that that method returns a data type of `int`. When you write this:

```
return "Incorrect ISBN";
```

You're trying to return a `String`. You can't do that. You *have* to return an integer.

What you might want to do is return a negative number if it's incorrect and print something out that says it's wrong. That way, you know not to use the invalid number, but still return an `int`.

Like this, for example:

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
   if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
       return ISBN;
   }else{
       System.out.println("Incorrect ISBN"); // print out that it's invalid
       return -1; // should be known that -1 means it's invalid
   }
}
```

---

As a note, your `set` methods don't make sense. A `set` method sets a field to a certain value. When you return something, it should be called a `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a wrong value(i.e `String`) in this following method.

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
     if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
         return ISBN;
     }else{
         return "Incorrect ISBN"; // Wrong
     }
}
```

return `int` instead of `String` as

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
    if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
        return ISBN;
    }else{
        return newISBN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function is declared to return an `int` but it's returning a String. This is a type mismatch.

You can fix this by using a special flag value for "incorrect", like -1 or something:

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
    if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
        return ISBN;
    }else{
        return -1; // or whatever
    }
}
```

However, I noticed you're using `setISBN()` like a *validation* function. I would suggest changing it to return a `boolean` and renaming it:

```
public boolean isValidIsbn(int newIsbn){       
    return ((newIsbn>=10000) &&(newIsbn<=20000));
}
```

This returns `true` if the ISBN is "valid" (by your definition) and `false` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

```
public int setISBN(int newISBN){       
       if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
           return ISBN;
       }else{
           return "Incorrect ISBN"; // must be int
       }
}
```

you are returning `String` i.e. `"Incorrect ISBN"` & `return type` of function is `int`.

So return somwthinh that is unique that ll identify that `ISBN` value is not between `10000 to 20000`, suppose return `0` & check there that value is `0` or not. Or more better if you make return type to `boolean`. so it ll be :

```
public boolean setISBN(int newISBN){       
       if((newISBN>=10000) &&(newISBN<=20000)){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
}
```